# How the data is handled with traits?

Tags: scala, traits

In Scala traits can hold not only methods but also data. Now I wonder how data is handled with traits -- I have in mind classic diamond problem, but also even such trivial cases as bringing two fields named the same (for example one from a super class and one from the trait).

If it is possible, how can user can specify she/he wants shared data or separate data?

Comment: There are lots of information about the topic on the web. But I prefer Martin's book and how he explains it: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html#12.5 In short traits are linearized in order they've written. But I recommend to read the link (till the end of the chapter). I think it is very important to understand them behind the scenes

Comment: @Archeg, I have this book on my shelf, I read that chapter before asking, and I am asking, because it discusses how `super` is resolved, not what is happening with the data. And if data are linearized I would still ask, because I don't know what is means to linearize fields (I would actually say it does not make sense, because the order is not important but name clashes).

Comment: I see, that explains your question. Remember that in scala a field is two methods + private field. So, private field stays private for each trait where it is defined, and the standard rules of linearization are applied to the methods

Comment: (removed comment by mistake). You cannot override `var` in scala. The above comment concerns only `val`. So there is always single method

Comment: @Archeg, "**a field** is two methods + private field. " -- you mean property? I am not asking about access levels, or overriding (you cannot override data). Does each parent holds its own copy of the data, or not? Or is it up to developer implementing derived class or trait?

Comment: See Alexey's answer. That's exactly what I meant

Answer (score 2):

Scala only has private fields, so they can't conflict; accessor methods can, but this is treated exactly the same as other methods. Namely, if one of the methods overrides the other, it is used; if neither does, you must implement the method overriding both in the derived class.

> Does each parent holds its own copy of the data, or not? Or is it up to developer implementing derived class or trait?

Traits don't *really* have fields, just methods. When these methods are `val`, the compiler will add a (private) field with the same name to when this trait is mixed into a class, and only at that time.

So in diamond problem there is only going to be one field from mixing in the grandparent, because it only appears once in the linearization; when

> two fields named the same (for example one from a super class and one from the trait)

if either of them uses `var`, it can't be overridden and it'll fail to compile; if both are `val` and the trait doesn't extend the superclass, the subclass will need to override both, creating a new field; if the trait extends the superclass, the subclass will get the field from the trait.

Comment: Thank you but I am still puzzled (maybe it is my English). "(and it can't reuse superclass fields)." It means in diamond problem that you will get distinct (separate) fields. But in next sentence you write "So in diamond problem there is only going to be one field from mixing in the grandparent" - it means the opposite, having shared field.

Comment: I think the last part about two fields named the same is wrong. If you name the fields the same they are either overriden or the compile issues an error, depending whether they are `val` or `var`. Either way you always have one field

Comment: @greenoldman You receive a single field per instance. No matter how complicated hierarchy you have (if fields have the same name). Just think about methods - the method behavior is also always single, no matter how complicate the overrides are. Surely you can call the superclass method implementation, but this is extending the current implementation, rather then having two of them - you cannot choose what implementation to use, you use them both always. And fields cannot be used over `super` as well.

Comment: @greenoldman "(and it can't reuse superclass fields)" is part of the condition for "when". I meant that if it can reuse fields (e.g. you just have `override val x` in class parameters) it will do so.

Comment: @Archeg Yes, you are right. Fixed (I was thinking about a slightly different and irrelevant thing there).

Comment: Quote from the book "Traits can, for example, declare fields and maintain state." My points is, you can include trait `A` with field `a` (state equals field) multiple times -- for example 1000 times, so if I read you correctly, in such case I will end up with 1000 independent fields `a`, one per each inclusion of this trait. Each inclusion of `A` will read its own `a`, and any change (if possible) will impact only its own `a`.

Comment: No. This quote is talking about fields as accessor methods, so multiple inclusions of `A` and multiple versions of `a` will be resolved by linearization. Only then actual fields in the JVM sense are added.